# Rails models and controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, model-view-controller, controller

I am new to development. I've read a few books on rails and often times they dive straight into examples. In some examples they generate resources which includes models, views, controllers etc. while in others they generate models only and vice versa. When should controllers be generated?It'd be great if someone could shed some lights to this to help me begin. Thanks.

Comment: Read this: http://wiki.c2.com/?ModelViewController . But your post is about to get put "on hold" for being too broad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple explanation would be :

Controllers talk to your views and models, they take requests from users (when a user is visiting your website, all requests go to the route.rb file, depending on how you set up the route.rb file the requests go to the right controller or directly to views, if you have static pages for example) and create responses.

Models are handling the hard stuff, they communicate with the database and add/remove/edit any new data in the database and provide the controller with the data it needs.

Views are just html files in which you can embed ruby code (views end with the .html.erb extension (erb is for embedded ruby)). They get the data they need from the database through controllers. The controller then sends the right views as a response to the user request.

When are you supposed to create a new view,controller or model? That's very hard to answer without an example. Every application is specific and require a good amount of experience to set up your MVC correctly.

This is the explanation from just another newbee in Rails, so don't take anything I wrote as completely true and correct.

I would suggest you to look into some books for beginners which walk you through the whole process of creating a fully functional website in Rails.

My suggestion would be to check out Michael Hartl's book [The Ruby on Rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/) or if you want to take a step further and learn Ruby and RoR in detail, visit [The Odin Project](https://www.theodinproject.com/). Both are completely free and helped me a lot understand how Rails works.

Answer (score 3):

You should do this tutorial : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html it pretty shows much everything about Rails concisely.

But basically ..

**Controllers** are files that are the first endpoint to routes. When you type an address in the navbar you end up in a controller first. Then, inside your controller an action is triggered (Show, Index, Update ...).

Actions can be blank it is not a problem. But most of the time there is some logic added. This logic can be loading some data, creating records in the database etc ...

Once the action is completed a **view** is triggered. This view corresponds to the controller action that has been just been visited. It is usually an ERB file that will eventually produce an HTML file after the server side scripting is completed.

**Models** sit alongside controllers and views: they handle all the database data. This includes validations for the fields of specific tables (does an uploaded file exceed max size, can a field of a record be blank etc ...). One database table = one model.